# Problem with Loop Cut

Tags: modeling

I am kinda new on blender and i've imported some model from a website to do some kind of archviz with it. I wanted to loop cut one of the faces of one object to refine it for the UV and, for some reason, i can't have a loop cut slicing all the way through.
Can you help me with that? I would be very thankful.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

an alternative to adding an edge loop would be to use the knife tool:
in edit mode (tab)
press 'k'
click on your first edge, click on your last edge
press 'enter'

Answer (score 4):

loop cut is not working because you have triangle faces rather than quads, so the loop cut tool doesn't know where to extend.  Should it go through the edge of the triangle that makes up the current face on the left or through the edge on the right.

If the faces are four sided, called *quads*, then the loop tool knows to go to the edge that's *opposite* of the face you're starting on, where *opposite* is defined as the one edge not directly connected.

Further, if you have a series of quads, the loop cut will continue through all of them, but it will stop as soon as you get to a face that's not four sided.

The usual alternative in your case is to use the [Knife Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html).  It's a *modal* tool, meaning that it has its own set of shortcut keys when it is operating.

To start a knife cut in edit mode use the shortcut <kbd>K.</kbd>

Since you want to start on the edge, hover the mouse over the edge and left click to start the knife cut.

Anytime you want another vertex, left click.

When you're finally done, hit Enter to accept the cut.

If your list vertex isn't on an edge, then the knife tool will add one more vertex.

The manual has more details about other options, but that should be enough to get you started.